# laravel pagination Method links does not exist

Tags: pagination, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am building a dynamic query using eloquent based on user inputs.

```
$query = \App\Model::query();
if($this == request('that')){
    $query->where(...); // building dynamic query based on user inputs
}
```

and finally user can type number of records shown per page in an html input field named ***count*** or checking a checkbox input type named ***all*** and following code completes dynamic query in back-end:

```
if (request('all')) {
    $result = $query->get();
}else {
    $result = $query->paginate(request('count'));
}
```

Also in front-end I have following code to show pagination links:

```
{{$result->links()}}
```

The problem is when user chooses to show all records we face following error:

> Method links does not exist.

links method is not callable when we retrieve objects via `get()` method. What is the best practice in order not to face this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `->get()` method return collection instead of paginator model `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator`. So I can recomment you send some addition variable from your controller which indicate if you need execute `$result->links()`. 
**Controller:**

```
return view('yourView', [showPagination => is_null(request('all'))]);
```

**View:**

```
@if($showPagination)
   {{$result->links()}}
@endif
```